# MvcSiteMapProvider and StructureMap in DynamicNodeProviderBase?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm trying to [make a dynamic sitemap using `MvcSiteMapProvider`](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Dynamic-sitemaps).

The problem is that `_jobService` is null, what am I doing wrong? I am using `IJobService` elsewhere so it is correctly configured e.g.

```
x.For<IJobService>().Use<JobService>();
```

Here's my code:

```
private IJobService _jobService
{
        get
        {
            return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IJobService>();
        }
}

public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection()
{
        List<JobViewModel> activeJobs = _jobService.GetJobs().ToList();

        // Create a node for each job
        foreach (var job in activeJobs)
        {
            var node = new DynamicNode();
            node.Title = job.Title;
            node.RouteValues.Add("id", job.Id);

            yield return node;
        }
}
```

This code only runs once as I am using it to create a `sitemap.xml` so it creates a few nodes then errors out when it comes to the dynamic nodes. If I refresh the page after the error I see the created `sitemap.xml` (minus the dynamic nodes e.g. `/job/1`, `/job/2`).

Comment: Is `GetDynamicNodeCollection` run every time the menu is refreshed, or  just once (ie, before DI has been initialised)?

Comment: Thanks for looking, I've updated the post at the end. It only runs once.

Comment: So is it running before the DI container has been initialised? That would certainly explain why its `null` at this point, and still be valid elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem was exactly, but I suspect it had something to do with the order of initialization - that is, the sitemap was being constructed before the DI container configuration code was run.

This has been fixed in MvcSiteMapProvider v4, as we are now using DI to configure the entire provider and have removed the dependency on Microsoft's SiteMapProvider model. That provider model was the source of nearly all of the headaches with MvcSiteMapProvider (caching, DI, performance, threading, initialization, etc).